# How to get customized date?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have used a `datepicker` in my `<input>` tag, and when I select a `date (like 2013-12-27)`, then I wanted the selected date to be displayed as `December 27, 2013` in my *script*.

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" required="true"/>
```

How can we achieve this?

Comment: I think you will have to 'play' with some CulturalInfo inside your code.

Comment: check this [link](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html)

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'MM d, yy' }).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the date format explicitly in jQuery.

Try this:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'MM dd, yy' });
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EkeW3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer following answer for custom date function library.

[Calculating Date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812152/calculating-date-in-javascript/40399250#40399250)

I have copied the below answer from above link

Please find attached link for [Date Library](https://github.com/digicorp/date-management) to get the custom calculation date and time functions.

To use it client side, download index.js and assertHelper.js and include that in your HTML.

```
<script src="assertHelper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    DateLibrary.getDayOfWeek(new Date("2015-06-15"),{operationType:"Day_of_Week"}); // Output : Monday
}
```

**You can use different functions as given in examples to get custom dates.**

To get First Day of quarter From Given Date

```
DateLibrary.getRelativeDate(new Date("2015-06-15"),
    {operationType:"First_Date",granularityType:"Quarters"}) // Output : Wed Apr 01 2015 00:00:00
```

If first day of week is Sunday, what date will be on Wednesday, if
 given date is 15th June 2015

```
DateLibrary.getRelativeDate(iDate,
    {operationType: "Date_of_Weekday_in_Week",
        startDayOfWeek:"Sunday",returnDayOfWeek:"Wednesday"}) // Output : Wed Jun 17 2015 00:00:00
```

If first day of week is Friday, what date will be on Tuesday of 3rd
 Week of 2nd month of 3rd quarter of year containing 15th June 2015 as
 one of the date.

```
DateLibrary.getRelativeDate(new Date("2015-06-15"),
    {operationType: "Date_of_Weekday_in_Year_for_Given_Quarter_and_Month_and_Week",
        startDayOfWeek:"Friday",returnDayOfWeek:"Tuesday", QuarterOfYear:3, MonthOfQuarter:2, WeekOfMonth:3}) // Output : 18th Aug 2015
```

If first day of week is Tuesday, what week number in year will be
 follow in 15th June 2015 as one of the date.

```
 DateLibrary.getWeekNumber(new Date("2015-06-15"),
    {operationType:"Week_of_Year",
        startDayOfWeek:"Tuesday"}) // Output : 24
```

There are Date Difference functions also available

```
 DateLibrary.getDateDifference(new Date("2016-04-01"),new Date("2016-04-16"),
    {granularityType: "days"}) //output 15
```

Function for Convert number to Timestr

```
DateLibrary.getNumberToTimeStr("345", {delimiter: ":"}) //output 00:03:45
```

It also supports Julian date conversion

```
 DateLibrary.julianToDate("102536") //output Fri Jun 20 2003 00:00:00
```